# aws: after restart ip changes and found this ip keep getting lot of requests

Tags: amazon-web-services, ip

I have an EC2 instance in aws.

I have restarted it.

Then my ip got changed

Then i found my nginx server is recieving lot of requests on this ip address

On my previous ip I didnt notice any such traffic.

Is this someone randomly sending requests to some random ip address which one of them happened to be mine

Or this was an ip which was used by someone. Later after terminating instance its now alloted to anyone new.

Comment: It could be either one of those. HTTP requests from bots are very common and IPs do get reallocated in AWS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An Amazon EC2 instance will change public IP address when it is Stopped and Started (but *not* when it is Restarted).

The public IP address comes from a **pool of addresses** that would have been used by previous Amazon EC2 instances. Thus, some services might be sending traffic to these addresses due to previous use.

Also, there is a lot of **automated "bot" traffic on the Internet** that is continually scanning and probing resources, attempting to subvert security and take control of resources. I invite you to look at the security log in your home router -- you will see a lot of traffic from systems trying to break into your computers. This could include standard security holes in WordPress, web servers, Windows, etc. It is just the nature of the Internet and is best avoided by using Security Groups to minimise the number of open ports and, preferably, the acceptable range of source IP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

The question has been answered by @John Rotenstein.

this is just a workaround

I found that Creating Elastic Ip  address in aws and assigning to the instance

- can help to keep the same ip and also
- save from bots (i am not sure, but curently i see no unneccessary traffic)